# i want to convert python string with bold, italic, different font size to html format

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, type-conversion, string-conversion

I want to convert python string with different charactersitics.

That python string might include bold, italic, different font size.

I used aspose.words. It worked well except the result always come out with red sign of that it is made with aspose.

I want to just change python string to html.

Substituing (like changing /n to '<-br->') can be an option in some cases, but i dont think it will work at different font size or bold.

The string would be like following

> HTML (Hypertext Markup Language) is a markup language used to create webpages and web applications. It is a standard markup language used to structure and present content on the web.

> Advantages of HTML:

> 1. **Easy to learn and use**: HTML is a relatively simple language to learn and use. It can be easily understood by most web developers, even those with no prior coding experience.

> 2. **Cross-platform compatibility**: HTML is compatible with all web browsers, allowing webpages to be viewed on any device.

> 3. **SEO friendly**: HTML is search engine friendly, making it easier for search engines to index and rank websites.

> 4. **Accessibility**: HTML provides accessibility features that make it easier for people with disabilities to access and interact with webpages.

> 5. **Low cost**: HTML is free to use, making it a cost-effective option for web development.

This is just a example but i cant figure out how to change this :(
Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of a python string, what you have tried, and the problem you're having achieving it? See how to create a [mcve], and [edit] the question.

Comment: Also, there are probably many third-party libraries that have already implemented this. Don't reinvent the wheel. Have a search.

Comment: well i just edited my question and upload an example. Plus, i thought that there is a lot of third-party libraries that would makes things easier.. but i cant find suitable one. I need some help to find out the correct way @PeterWood

Comment: That's not a python string.

Comment: Assuming you liked Apose markdown output, see: https://pypi.org/project/html2markdown/

Comment: You can use [Aspose.Words Cloud SDK for Python](https://products.aspose.cloud/words/python/) for the conversion, it does not add any watermark. It is a paid API, but it provides 150 free API calls per month.